# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints error

Tags: swift, cell, uitableview

is "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" a serious issue that will have an app rejected from AppStore as a result? Im having this issue, but the app works great with it. The issue is because I'm having Visual Format Constraints working together with AutoLayout to achieve what I want in the aspect of changing the width of a UILabel in a custom cell.
Basically, switching "translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints" on and off.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: no, they're not checking your code. Just entitlements, violations, and overally if the app doesnt crash just by using it. If they rejected for storyboard warnings they oh boy

Comment: @FruitAddict Thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 0):

Your app will not be rejected just because it generates "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" warnings. Also I would recommend you to fix this warnings, because they warn about wrong constraints being setup for your view, and your view can behave strangely in some situations or in future iOS releases. By the way, I suggest using open-source Autolayout frameworks, they will save tons a lot of your time :)

- https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit for Swift
- https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry for Objective-C

Comment: Thanks MIsternewb. A silly question: How do I add this open-source framework to my Xcode?